# Problem in textbook regarding function composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I feel like this is a weird question,and I have no idea how to answer this.

Explain why the following errors committed by beginners can be explained by noting that functions do not always commute under composition.

$\frac{1}{x+4}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{4}$.

I feel like this question wants me to use the fact that $(f \circ g)(x)=(g \circ f)(x)$ is not usually true. I proceed by defining $f(x)=x+4$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.Then $g(f(x))=\frac{1}{x+4}$.But $f(g(x))=\frac{1}{x}+4$.I know this is a lame attempt but honestly, I do not even understand what the question is asking.Or I am missing something obvious.Can someone explain how I should approach this problem?

Comment: It seems that the idea was to take g(x,y)=x+y  and f(z)=1/z.

Comment: I think your suggestion is probably what they intended but, as you remark, it doesn't really work they way they had hoped.  Oddly, it would work if you replace $4$ by $1$.

Comment: I would argue that the conceptual error illustrated here is the belief that all functions are linear.  People frequently write, say, $\log (a+b)=\log a + \log b$ or $\sqrt {a+b}=\sqrt a +\sqrt b$.  Here, of course, the notion would be that the function $f(x)=\frac 1x$ is linear, hence $f(x+4)=f(x)+f(4)$.

Comment: @lulu Ok Thanks